# Relate two tables based on geom

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I have a problem, which is, I have a table ways (like in the [Workshop of pgRouting](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/index.html)) and I also have a different table `street_name`, where it contains the name of the street (among other information). Both have a column `geom` and I want to connect a given edge of the `pgr_dijkstra` calculated route with the name of the nearest point in `street_name`. I'm already using a version of [this function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/80300/60308) to convert lat/long in source/target values. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an example into the blue, because no routing code and not very fast O(N^2)! I have a configuration of windmills (point data) in the table `windmills` and surrounding objects in the table `objects` (polygon data). Create a view or a FROM-Statement as follows.

```
CREATE VIEW dist_mill_object AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.gid) 
   a.gid AS obj_id, 
   b.gid AS mill_id,   
   a.cell_name,
   b.mill_number, 
   st_shortestline(st_centroid(a.geom), b.geom) AS geom
 FROM objects as a, 
      windmills as  b
 ORDER BY 
   a.gid, 
   st_distance(st_centroid(a.geom), b.geom);
```

So you get the shortest `a.gid`, `b.gid` pair.